# Minecraft coordinates unavailable, how can I find them

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't find where I'm going or what depth level I'm on. How do I turn on my coordinates? Are they even on mcpe? Also, can villagers trade yet?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, don't mark a question as a dupe and then mark that as a dupe of another question. Dupe duplicates to **one canonical** question, don't make a dupe trail.

Comment: @Vemonus My apologies. I hadn't noticed the XY question until after I'd sent my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can find coordinates in Minecraft PE is to do the command, `/tp ~ ~ ~` in the chat box it will report `Teleported PlayerName to x y z`. Y is the vertical level.

No, villager trading has not been implemented as of version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

[Villager trading is coming in MCPE 1.0.4.](https://mcpehq.com/news/villager-trading-coming-minecraft-pe-1-0-4-update/). One of the devs posted a screenshot of the 1.0.4 beta test change log and the first item mentioned is villager trading being added. Of course, until they push the 1.0.4 update to everyone, only beta testers can play around with it.

For the time being, finding your coordinates requires an [add on](http://mcpedl.com/coordinates-unlocker-addon/)  or using the method ( /tp ~ ~ ~ ) that ghostpotato shared.

Answer (score -1):

As of right now villager trading is available in the current update of 1.0.4. Also as far as coordinates I have been using this particular Addon http://mcpedl.com/nextlevel/ I personally consider it to be the coordinates addon available.